# Java: Easiest way to convert Calendar to String and back

Tags: java

My application uses an API that accepts only a `Map<String, String>`. Therefore, all objects must be converted to this form before they can be passed to the API.

This is quite trivial for simple classes like `Boolean, BigDecimal` etc. But it is proving somewhat problematic for converting a `Calendar` object.

I am not overly familiar with all the nuances of Calendars/Dates etc in Java so would appreciate some advice on converting my Calendar to a String and then back again.

When my application receives a request, it already has the Calendar constructed. It must then convert this to a String (1), pass it through the API (2), and then convert it back to a Calendar (3) on the other side.

So I am in control of 1 and 3, but not 2.

Based on this, what is the easiest way to convert to and then from a String?

Thanks

Comment: Don't see what is wrong with this question. I'm asking for a way to convert a Calendar to a String, and then back, which has been successfully answered below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the best thing to do is use `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`, store it as a `String` version of that `long` value, and then `Calendar.getInstance().setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(Map.get(strIndex)))` to get the Calendar back.

Comment: Thanks, presumably that won't maintain any Timezone information? Timezone will be the same on both sides, so maybe I can ignore that

Comment: Well, I mean, you could add `Locale` information as another parameter to your `Map`